# Multiple modal dialogs - can not cancel or submit the second modal dialog

Tags: modal-dialog, dialog-framework

I have problems with multiple modal dialogs using IE 9 browser.
When I click on the Ok or Cancel button on the second modal form, I get following exception from my js code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4PMj.jpg

when I try once again to press Ok or Cancel button I get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/52idM.jpg

### It works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

on my first dialog I have a link button  and this fires a standard js function

```
function AddContributor(id) {

    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    currentUrl = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = currentUrl + "/SecondPage.aspx?id=" + id;
    options.title = "Add";
    options.width = 700;
    options.height = 600;
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = AddContributorCallback;

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

function AddContributorCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
    if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('xxx');
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult);
    }
    if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
         SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('xxx.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first looking at your code you have taken the if statment out of the try catch block where it should be inside the try block so you can catch the error when debugging.

The next issue is that it returning null, probably because its out of the try catch block and/or the object doesnt exist in that time when your clicking on it so your calling somthing (object) that hasnt been created yet or has been desposed off causing it to be null.

as i cant properly see a part of the code that could be causing it I can only speculate that you have click on the first modal which runs fine but then on the second one it throws the error as it doesnt exist what your calling or the code that its failing on is not in the right place!

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code you have seen is not my code. It's standard sharepoint modal-dialog js.

Comment: ok no problem, so how did you add the dialog?

Comment: I have updated my question above.